# Other references of incidents described in Uttar Kand in Ramayana

Tags: ramayana

'Uttarkand' of Ramayana is often criticized as a later addition to the original text and not written by Rishi Valmiki. I want to know if the incidents described in Uttarkand have any references in any other Hindu books or texts. If so then the incidents can be verified with other texts.

Comment: Sita's banishment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29374/661

Comment: Shambukh vadha: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40675/do-any-authentic-scriptures-other-than-valmiki-ramayan-talk-about-shambukas-sto

Comment: It is a broad question as there are many incidents in Uttara Khanda.